# ATI graphical driver installation error

Tags: ati, configuration

I just installed ATI driver, but when I am trying to start tha AMD/ATI Control center, I'm getting the following error:

There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.  It could be caused by the following.

No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly.
Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Did you reboot afer installing it?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to uninstall and install it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions listed on the [ATI Wiki page](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation) for Ubuntu 11.10.

I personally have never had any luck installing them using the manual method listed, I download the installation .run file and then `cd` into the folder I've downloaded it to then type `sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-9-x86.x86_64.run` which starts the ATI GUI installer process.

I have had issues with the 11.9 Catalyst version (which is the latest) and three different ATI cards so I've installed 11.8 via 'Additional Drivers' and had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with running aticonfig. It breaks my install. If the answer above by Mark works, might be worth the effort. Else, the open source equivalent is available. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver